# null element return when using following and preceding XPath selector

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to find the preceding element (Input) using Selenium Driver with the help of Xpath selector ( I have access to Label) which works very well using Chrome Developer Tool - F12 Option But return the null using below code line.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='myDvId']/label/preceding-sibling::input[1])"));
```

My actual HTML looks like

```
<div id="myDvId">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chxInputId"></input> <!-- THIS IS INPUT CHECKBOX WITH NO ID or CLASS NAME -->
    <label for="chxInputId">My Label<label>
</div>
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you give me the site url? In the xpath you have given id = myDvId but in the html, the id actually "myDvI".There is a chance that your xpath is referring to some other part of the dom.

Comment: First run `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='myDvId']/label"))` to make sure you can identify the label

Comment: @santhoshkumar that was a typo. The Id of the DIV is "myDvId".

Comment: @TarunLalwani.. Label is identified with no issue. Just not able to locate the Input.. Thanks for response

Comment: is this working? driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='myDvId']/input)"));

Comment: This is working. but my intention is to only use the preceding as I have certain limitations.

Comment: It worked when I changed the method driver.FindElement to **driver.FindElements**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify the `<input>` tag with respect to the `<label>` tag with text as **My Label** you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='myDvId']/label[contains(.,'My Label')]//preceding::input[1])"));
```

---

### Update

As per your comment, you can remove the parent `<div>` tag from your *xpath* as the dependency is on the text of the `<label>` and use :

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[contains(.,'My Label')]//preceding::input[1])"));
```

Comment: It works until we have XPath like: By.XPath("//div[@id='myDvI']/label[contains(.,'My Label')]
but then, if we add preceding selector it doesn't return me the node.

Comment: @Sandip Check my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: When I updated the code to use driver.**FindElements**(By.XPath("//*[@id='myDvId']/label/preceding-sibling::input[1])"));

it started working. But thank you so much for the initiative to look and answer.